# has_many through a has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models, `Conversation` and `Message`, and one concern `Conversible`. A `Conversible` has one `Conversation` and a `Conversation` has many `Message`'s. I'd like to set up `Conversible` so I can call `messages` on my `Conversible` and it will return the `Message`'s for its `Conversation`. Here's what I have so far:

```
module Conversible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :conversation, as: :conversible dependent: :destroy
    has_many :messages, through: :conversation
  end
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversible, polymorphic: true
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I can call `conversible.messages`, but it always returns an empty relation, even when `conversible.conversation.messages` returns a relation with its `Message`'s.

What am I missing?

Comment: where do you include your module `Conversible`?

Comment: We have four other models that will include `Conversible`. For example, there's a `Goal` model that should have a `Conversation`. I left them out to try and keep the question simple.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you don't need `Conversible` module:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversible, polymorphic: true
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

and then if you need some relation for `Conversation` you could write:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations, as: :conversible
end
```

or you could try something like:

```
module Conversible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included 
    has_one :conversations, as: :conversible
    has_many :messages, through: :conversations
  end
end
```

and then:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Conversible
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is a sample from a bigger project. We have multiple models in our application that will include `Conversible`, as well as other methods that will be added to that concern.